# How can I remove inner parentheses from an R string?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am processing strings in R which are supposed to contain zero or one pair of parentheses.  If there are nested parentheses I need to delete the inner pair.   Here is an example where I need to delete the parentheses around *big bent nachos* but not the other/outer parentheses.

```
test <- c(
  "Record ID", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos (big bent nachos))", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)", 
  "Complete?"
)
```

I know I can kill all the parentheses with the `stringr` package using `str_remove_all()`:

```
test |>
  stringr::str_remove_all(stringr::fixed(")")) |> 
  stringr::str_remove_all(stringr::fixed("("))
```

but I don't have the RegEx skills to pick the inner parentheses.  I found a [SO post that is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546777/use-regex-to-remove-outer-parentheses-from-nested-expression-but-leave-inner-pa) but it removes the outer parentheses and I cant untangle it to remove the inner.

Comment: Do you also want to delete the content of the inner paranthesis? Also do you have just one inner paranthesis or multiple inner paranthesis? ie `here(a(b(c)))` do you want `here(a)` or `here(abc)`?

Comment: I only need to delete the inner `(`  and `)` characters.  The content needs to remain.

Comment: So you need to have `here(abc)`?? Do you have at most one nested parenthesis or is it more than one nested parenthesis?

Comment: A [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) idea for multiple inside: [`\(([^)(]*)\)(?=(?:[^)(]*\([^)(]*\))*[^)(]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/zgRkL5/1) (replace with `$1`) - [Recursive regex](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) if nested: [`(?:\G(?!^)|\()[^)(]*\K(\(((?>[^)(]+|(?1))*)\))`](https://regex101.com/r/zgRkL5/2) (replace with `$2`) - Use with `gsub` (`perl=T`)

Comment: @onyambu I think the example with Tacos above is as complex as it will get.

Comment: @bobblebubble That is wildly impressive.  Did you use an app to help write that?  I ask because I can't imagine ever having the skill to do that without serious help.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami Just love regexing :) I had previously put an answer but thought it's too much for the provided samples. However it could be useful in future or for someone with a similar task! Rephrased my answer a bit and restored it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
test |>
  stringr::str_replace_all("(\\().*\\(", "\\1") |> # remove inner open brackets
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\)(?=.*\\))") # remove inner closed brackets
```

```
[1] "Record ID"                                       
[2] "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)"          
[3] "What is the best food? (big bent nachos)"        
[4] "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)"
[5] "Complete?"
```

##### EDIT

Fixed my solution, so as to not lose text:

```
test |>
  stringr::str_replace("\\((.*)\\(", "(\\1") |> # remove inner open brackets
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\)(?=.*\\))") # remove inner outer brackets
```

```
[1] "Record ID"                                            
[2] "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)"               
[3] "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos big bent nachos)"
[4] "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)"     
[5] "Complete?"
```

Comment: FYI: "choice=Tacos " missing from item 3.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Dave2e, I didn't realise. See my solution now, I've fixed it. All in one step and rather simple :) Thanks.

Comment: @JoshWhite Thank you for the Tidyverse friendly solution!  Do you have a favorite website and/or book for learning RegEx?

Comment: No sorry. For me it has just been time, the more I use it the better I get. So just keep practicing!

Answer (score 2):

Interested in how this would be solved with multiple `(`...`)` inside the outer parentheses, I came up with the following [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based idea. It only checks for an outer closing parentheses though.

```
test <- gsub("\\(([^)(]*)\\)(?=[^)(]*(?:\\([^)(]*\\)[^)(]*)*\\))", "\\1", test, perl=T)
```

See [this R demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZCxbsMwDER3fwWhiSzcoWtRw0O6ZOnQBuhQt4As05GARDIsGkW/3qXiZM/Ed7o7gtC8rsJZ4OURHFYA5p1dmgfYv5oaiv70ViBkEM/Ql@SY0tACOp@C4@bNKmS6L3ywLmXAPhzVjQJxK9/Z3vkwZfgN4iHLMo632i6dpxMLt6Yu8iMBoviQCVJkQG@V8Gzjn44QcxiYlGIxPc@s3C@iuQvbOFyRTEVVdfucY156NF2H@PVD@P1AXUfYNpvA9lmdjfX9mihYbtTWk46yqYaJ51NzoMvedf0H) or a [pattern demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vdYIjc/2) (replace with `\1`, [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of *first group*)

The lookahead verifies at each `(`...`)` if only followed by `(`....`)` or [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-parentheses up to `)`.

---

If there is even arbitrary nesting, flattening the first level could be solved by a [recursive regex](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html).

```
test <- gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\()[^)(]*+\\K(\\(((?>[^)(]+|(?1))*)\\))", "\\2", test, perl=T)
```

One more [R demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZDBasMwDIbveQotJ6nNYOuxrMuhhTEGO2yFHeYVnESJDakdYocx6LtnSrqyaw9Cnyz9v4X6cYwcIjzcQokJQPrGpe8reN6lGUz1h9ERbIBoGIppsva@ygFL423Jm1ctEOi64b0ufQAsbCNdF8GdxVeqt8Z2Ab5tNBDiUNcX2dYfu5Yj52k2le8eEKOxgcA7BjRaCI/a/UiyLtiKSchNTcM9CxdDlLmZtav@kM52O@aOe3Cyj3XNGrC9k7iXWBH8Z7H0k4sWN5pDCEuC4tJxntKEkuRy7iYMBaaYr5V6wvzmQCelkD4PhF@LpVIvKCVi/ji/LE@Yyx8LUmo@V6rUStLklYHs1272NDuP4y8) or a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgRkL5/4) (replace with `\2`, the *second group's* capture)

| regex-part | explained |
| --- | --- |
| `(?:\G(?!^)|\()` | Matches an opening bracket for [chaining matches to by use of `\G`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex) |
| `[^)(]*+\K` | Consumes [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-parentheses and [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) the beginning |
| `(\(((?>[^)(]+|(?1))*)\))` | Matching the nested parentheses ([explanation at php.net ↗](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)). It contains two [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): • the *first* recurses at `(?1)` • the *second* captures `(`*inside*`)`. |

Here the matches are chained to the opening parentheses. There is no check for an outer closing `)`.
This `\G` based idea can be used [without recursion](https://regex101.com/r/myhRMS/2) too for just one level but is slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there be at most one nested parentheses, we could use a `gsub()` approach:

```r
output <- gsub("\\(\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\(.*?\\)(.*?)\\s*\\)", "(\\1\\2)", test)
output

[1] "Record ID"                                       
[2] "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)"          
[3] "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos)"           
[4] "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)"
[5] "Complete?"
```

**Data:**

```
test <- c(
  "Record ID", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos (big bent nachos))", 
  "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)", 
  "Complete?"
)
```

Comment: Tim,  "I need to delete the inner pair" did not imply, **at least to me**, deleting the contents within the ( ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using gsub from base R.  It is broken down into 2 steps for readability and debugging.

```
test <- c(
   "Record ID", 
   "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)", 
   "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos (big bent nachos))", 
   "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)", 
   "Complete?"
) 

test <- gsub("(\\(.*)\\(", "\\1", test)
# ( \\(.*  ) - first group starts with '(' then zero or more characters following that first '('
#  \\(       - middle part look of a another '('

#  "\\1" replace the found group with the part from the first group

test <-gsub("\\)(.*\\))", "\\1", test)
#similer to first part
test

[1] "Record ID"                                            
[2] "What is the best food? (choice=Nachos)"               
[3] "What is the best food? (choice=Tacos big bent nachos)"
[4] "What is the best food? (choice=Chips with stuff)"     
[5] "Complete?"
```

Comment: `I need to delete the inner pair`

Comment: Thank you!  That is a wonderful example to learn from.  Can you offer advice for good places where to learn RegEx?  I love books.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami, Here is a complete tutorial: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: If you make it to Miami, lunch is on me.